How to exclude "xs:type" tag when extending a transient
Desired outcome:
Easily switch between
<root>
  <child>
    <prop1>..</prop1>
    <prop2>..</prop2>
  </child>
<root>

and
<root>
  <child>
    <prop1>..</prop1>
    <prop2>..</prop2>
    <prop3>..</prop3>
    <prop4>..</prop4>
  </child>
</root>

My code
Root.java
@XmlRootElement(name= "root")
public class Root {
  @XmlElement(name="child")
  public Child child
}

ExtendedRoot.java
@XmlRootElement(name= "root")
public class ExtendedRoot extends Root {
  @XmlElement(name="child")
  public ExtendedChild child
}

Child.java
@XmlTransient
public class Child {
  // prop1, prop2
}

ExtendedChild.java
@XmlType(propOrder = {"prop1", "prop3","prop4", "prop2"})
public class ExtendedChild extends Child {
  // prop3, prop4
}

Main
System.setProperty("javax.xml.bind.context.factory", "org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory")
Class clazz = extendChild ? ExtendedRoot.class : Root.class;
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(clazz);
Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
marshaller.marshal(formattedJob, tempFile);

Actual outcome
<root>
  <child xs:type="ExtendedChild">
    <prop1>..</prop1>
    <prop2>..</prop2>
    <prop3>..</prop3>
    <prop4>..</prop4>
  </child>
</root>

How can I exclude this xs:type=... from the child tag?

Your question and code sample is not understandable properly. Can you please separate the code chunks and elaborate

The xs:type is used here because the value of the child property is polymorphic. Without it JAXB doesn't have a chance to decide which class to use when reading your own XML documents. JAXB isn't that clever to first introspect the element and then select the best fitting class.
But there are some other points while reading XML:
Are you aware, that ExtendedRoot has two properties named child (the one inherited from Root, super.child and its own, this.child)? Since ExtendedChild is a Child also an ExtendedChild may be stored to either of the two properties:

First you may wonder where your child elements turn up in your objects.
Because you can store an ExtendedChild to Root.child there is no necessity for ExtendedRoot.child. Without this there is even no necessity for ExtendedRoot in this example.

If you insist on keeping ExtendedRoot be aware that JAXB can't decide wether to use Root or ExtendedRoot if it stumbles about a root element.

Hi Karsten. The use case is that I need to produce an xml which may or may not include a certain prop, and I wanted to be able to toggle this based on a condition. The xml is for sending to different third parties, so our system has no requirement to be able to read it back again. I could achieve the desired outcome by just having two completely different classes with no inheritance but I was hoping to find a more elegant way given the significant overlap of the properties

If you use polymorphism there is no easy way to get rid of the type attribute e..g. by configuring the marshaller. Maybe you can avoid polymorphism by additionally making your Child abstract and then creating some root classes which don't derive from each other.
